# Is it possible to join multiple channels as audience at the same time in agora.io?

Tags: agora.io

currently I am using Agora Web SDK for Live Streaming. In my website Multiple users can live stream at the same time. so i want to show multiple live streams on single page. so for that i am calling join method multiple time and it gives me "Client already in connecting/connected state" Error. so i have to leave previous stream before joining another stream. is there any solution so that i can join multiple channels( Live Streams ) at the same time as Audience. ? so that i can see multiple streams at the same time ?

Answer (score 0):

Agora has a detailed blog explaining how you can join multiple livestream channels at once. Check it out here: https://www.agora.io/en/blog/connecting-to-multiple-channels-with-the-agora-web-sdk/